# Solr schema for range values

Tags: design-patterns, solr, filter, schema

I have created following kind of schema in SOLR for indexing "Age High" and "Age Low" fields

```
<field name="age"  type="age-levels-facet" multiValued="true" indexed="true"  stored="true" />

<fieldtype name="age-levels-facet" class="solr.TextField">
          <analyzer>
            <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern=";"/>
            <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="^(([0-2]))?$" replacement="Birth-2" replace="all" />
            <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="^(([3-5]))?$" replacement="3-5" replace="all" />
            <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="^(([6-8]))?$" replacement="6-8" replace="all" />
            <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="^(([9]|1[0-2]))?$" replacement="9-12" replace="all" />
            <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="^((1[3-9]|[2-9][0-9]))?$" replacement="13+" replace="all" />
          </analyzer>
        </fieldtype>
```

So if, I pass "age=4-12" it will return me result as follow.

```
Birth-2 (0)
3-5 (1)
6-8 (0)
9-12 (1)
13+(0)
```

Which is correct as per I have created schema. But not correct logically. e.g. for user with age group of 4-12, the result would be

```
Birth-2 (0)
3-5 (1)
6-8 (1)
9-12 (1)
13+(0)
```

Anyone have any idea, how I can achieve this, using solr????

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to bake these in? Just use Solr [Facet by Range](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Facet_by_Range) functionality or [Facet by Query](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Facet_Fields_and_Facet_Queries). Then, you can just store your age as a number.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Alexandre. The reasone I need to do these is, the product I am trying to index with solr, has fields like "Age High" and "Age Low". So user with given range can possibly search these products.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I understand what that changes. You seem to want to index numbers. You also seem to want to search numbers ranges. The solution above does it. If you want to map particular queries to specific user name (e.g. High Age => value > 55), you can do that on a client.

I think the confusion might be around "I pass age=4-12". That's not Solr syntax. Perhaps clarifying specifically the index and search values more clearly will help to understand what you want to happen.